# FatalExecutionEngineError On FileDialog.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, wpf, filedialog

This is my program's basic Information:

- WPF Application
- Target Framework: 4
- Platform Target: Any CPU

Now when I try to open a file dialog I get a FatalExecutionEngineError.

This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog OF = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
OF.Filter = " All File (*.*)|*.*";

bool? res = OF.ShowDialog();

if (res == true)
{
// Do Some Code
}
```

Error Discription:

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
>   Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xe80fc200, on thread 0x1fbc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Comment: You'll need to get your machine stable again.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6718336/17034

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` instead of `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: hi, i use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog Before But its already return similar error.