# Why does OpenFileDialogue cause failure in debug on a C# Forms Application?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, openfiledialog

I've been trying to find a solutions for this issue the past 2 days.  Basically when I'm debugging my form app, I have a button with an onclick event handler.  Here is the code in my handler.

```
private void btnBrowseReqDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     OpenFileDialog FileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
     FileDlg.InitialDirectory = m_ConfigFile.GetReqDocDir();
     FileDlg.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Word 97-2003 (*.doc)|*.doc|Word 2007 (*.docx)|*.docx";
     FileDlg.FilterIndex = 1;

     if (FileDlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
        txtWordReqDoc.Text = FileDlg.FileName;

        SetProgressControls(false);
     }

     this.btnExecute.Enabled = CanEnableExecuteBtn();
     lblStatus.Visible = !(CanEnableExecuteBtn());
  }
```

About 60% to 70% of the time, this action will not complete.  A partial window appears but at this point it is basically the window of death.  I have to reboot to recover my machine.  This problem doesn't seem that uncommon.  Based on my research most people seem to feel this has to do with threading.  My program.cs has always had this attribute set.  Here is my program.cs code.

```
  static class Program
{
  /// <summary>
  /// The main entry point for the application.
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new MainForm());
  }
}
```

So is this just some kind of threading contention?  Why does it work sometimes and not work other times??  Should the OpenFileDialogue be run in a background process perhaps??  I have a workaround for the issue while I debug (which is basically just paste in the file path), I just wanted to learn more about this behavior here if at all possible.

Comment: Does this same thing occur if you put the add the OpenFileDialog in the designer and use it instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: An interesting idea.  So we gave it try.  Dropped an open file dialogue directly on the form and used it in the handler.  Same behavior.  Thanks though.

Comment: Tested your code (minus a few lines which reference functions that you haven't posted code for) and it works fine. Have you tried this code in a new empty WinForms application? Have you tried just showing the dialog without setting up any of the additional properties? Also, can you share some of your research which led you believe that this is "not that uncommon"?

Comment: Probably a shell extension that integrates into Explorer and gets loaded with the file open dialog. (e.g. something like TortoiseSVN which shows overlay icons). Try disabling them.

Comment: @vesan here are a few links I went through before I posted anything here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718148/windows-forms-gui-hangs-when-calling-openfiledialog-showdialog  http://wishmesh.com/2011/06/call-to-openfiledialog-or-savefiledialog-hangs-or-freezes/  They all seem to mainly reference using STA.  Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasWeller.  Can you give me anymore details about finding the shell extension and how to disable them??  Thanks!

Comment: There are too many of them. Right click in Explorer and see what the context menu shows. Anything which is not there in a clean OS installation is suspect.

Comment: @ThomasWeller  thanks, I think I have better I idea what you mean now and how I check that.  I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @vesan when you tested my code, what were your env variables? Like what version of Visual Studio, What OS were you on, etc?

Comment: @ThomasWeller  - Just FYI , I disabled all shell extensions of type 'Context Menu' that were not Microsoft Windows Operating System.  McAfee, WinZip and SnagIt, were really the only non standard OS shell extensions I could see.  I used ShellExView to disable.  Still had the same problem.

Comment: @vesan Just an FYI - created a very simple Open Dialogue example in another project.  Still had the same issue.