# Why ShowDialog-response delayed in async event handlers?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, modal-dialog

In my `.NET Framework 4.5` Windows Forms project I have an async event handler. In the event handler I open a `OpenFileDialog` with `ShowDialog()`. Then I want to do something async with the selected file.
But I have some weird behavior: After closing the dialog (with `Cancel` or `OK` button) I have got a delay of 9 seconds until the `ShowDialog` returned with its result. While this time the application is freezed.

Here my code:

```cs
private async void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this);
    if (result != DialogResult.OK) // <- delayed more than 9 seconds after user closes dialog
        return;

    await this.LoadFileAsync(this.openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

After I remove the keyword `async` then the code behaves as expected:

```cs
private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this);
    if (result != DialogResult.OK) // -> no delay here
        return;

    this.LoadFileAsync(this.openFileDialog.FileName); // works, but compiler warning, because missing (await-keyword)
}
```

Can somebody please explain this behavior?
Thanks.

Yes, I know the workaround: I could use the event handler of the dialog `FileOk` and move my code to this event handler. But I am curious about the documented behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure someone can replicate this. If a User chooses `Cancel`, then the method returns. Otherwise, it depends on what `LoadFileAsync()` is actually doing. If it's something blocking, the calling Form freezes. The dialog is closed before that anyway. Unless you *forgot* to mention some details about the context of these operations (other Tasks / Threading involved). Or some Shell extensions you have that can get in the way.

Comment: Could you include the `LoadFileAsync` method in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a little bit. I think I was wrong. It does not depends on the `async` keyword.

It seems it is a Windows Forms bug.
See also: [Windows Forms GUI hangs when calling OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718148/windows-forms-gui-hangs-when-calling-openfiledialog-showdialog)

If I set `ShowHelp` property to `true`. Then it works without delay. But its a different Open File Dialog (at least on latest Windows 10).

```cs
this.openFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;
```